# what is differences between var a = b = 2 and var a = 2; var b=2;

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

when i declare variable in a function, i face a problem.

```
var b = 44;
function test(){
    var a = b = 2;
}
```

But this works fine:

```
 var b = 44;
 function test(){
    var a;
    var b = 2;
 }
```

Variable b over rides the global b variable.

I cannot find any documentation about this behavior.

Is there any documentation about it ?

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/uq4nxk1k/1/

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, so any variables declared inside it stay within that scope.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you can find a documentation, but here's the explanation about the result you obtained :

**Local > Global**

When you declare a global variable, it's available anywhere in your file. 
Inside "test()", when you write :

```
var a = b = 2;
```

you are creating a new variable a, that take the value of the global variable b and changing, at the same time, the value of b to 2 -> you are overriding his value.

When you write (inside test()) :

```
var a, b;
```

or

```
var a; 
var b;
```

you're declaring two more variables, that are only known inside your function and, as local > global, if you write b = 2, you can face two situations :

1. if you console.log(b) inside test(), you obtain 2
2. if you console.log(b) outside test(), you obtain 44

**Declaration != Assignment**

Very very important ->

- var a, b; **is a declaration**
- a = b = 25; **is an assignment (I'd say double assignment)**
- var a = b = 25 **is a declaration and an assignment at the same time**.

I hope it helps!!!:) Just tell me if something is unclear or if you need any other explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`var` in a function scope doesn't override the variables declared in outer scope. Let me explain what your `test()` function does:

```
// these variables are global:
var a = "out";
var b = "out";
var c = "out";
var d = "out";
var e = "out";
var f = "out";
var g = "out";


function test() {
    // the following line is equal to
    // var a; var b; var c = "in";
    var a, b, c = "in"; 
    // the local variable b gets a value of "in"
    b = "in";
    // the following means:
    // declare local d which references global e which references global f
    // and assign "in" to them; which is why only global e and global f are changed to "in";
   // *edit more like: f = "in"; e = f; var d = e;
    var d = e = f = "in";
    // declare local variable g and assign "in" to it
    var g = "in";
}
test();
// here back in the global scope a, b, c, d and g were not changed
// so a == "out", b == "out", c == "out", d == "out" and g == "out"
// but e == "in" and f == "in" because you've changed them from within test()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just to note**

When you declare with primitive values:

```
var a = b = 2;
```

Equivalent to:

```
var b = 2;
var a = b;
```

As you realize, both `a` and `b` are assigned with the same value.

However, when you assign object instead of primitive values:

```
var a = b = [1,2,3,4];
```

This is also equivalent to:

```
var b = [1,2,3,4];
var a = b;
```

**Which means both `a` and `b` share the same reference.
So any changes you made on `b` will affect `a`, and vice versa:**

```
a.push(5); 
// a <--- [1,2,3,4,5] 
// b <--- [1,2,3,4,5] !! be ware of this! b will also get this effect
```

**Keep in mind**: When you use a shortand `a = b = c = value`. All variables will be assigned with the same value. But in case of object assignment, all variables will share the same reference which refers to a value. Anytime you use this, always be aware of this effect.

Therefore, for object assignment, this definition:

```
var a = b = [1,2,3,4]; // change a WILL affect b
```

**is not producing exactly the same effect as**

```
var a = [1,2,3,4]; var b = [1,2,3,4]; // change a won't affect b
```

Comment: `var a = b = 2;` is equal to `var a; b = 2; a = b;` and it will create a global `b`: http://jsfiddle.net/ujgnsbry/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're declaring variables inside the function that won't be recognised by `$(".resultg").text("g = " + g);`

But in `var d = e = f = "in";` you're declaring a new local variable "d" that is equal to global variables `e` and `f`, and then assign "in" to all of them. As `e` and `f` are global variables, only in this case "in" reassignment will be recognised by `$(".resultg").text("g = " + g);`

Answer (score 0):

The question is not strange also the answer is not strange it is simple. The thing is just global variable concept

// the below `a,b,c,d,e,f,g` are global variable

```
var a = "out";
var b = "out";
var c = "out";
var d = "out";
var e = "out";
var f = "out";
var g = "out";
```

---

so now `a,b,c,d,e,f,g` are assigned with a value 'out'

so if you are yrying to alert anyone it will result out

// your function starts here

```
    function test() {
        var a, b, c = "in"; // Here a,b,c are local variables and never overright the global variable values 
    so this statement is meaning less when we try to print values from outside this function 

        b = "in";//here is the trick happends and confusion begins actually the b is our local variable created in the test function it is not global 
so when we change the value of b here it will not affect the global one 

var d = e = f = "in"; // the same thing happend here to here e,f are global and d is local // so if we try to print the global variable values we got 
    a=out
    b=out
    c=out
    d=out
    e=in
    f=in 
    g=out

        var g = "in";

    then here also it is a local variable so result will be 
    a=out
    b=out
    c=out
    d=out
    e=in
    f=in 
    g=out

    }

    test();

    $(".resulta").text("a = " + a);
    $(".resultb").text("b = " + b);
    $(".resultc").text("c = " + c);
    $(".resultd").text("d = " + d);
    $(".resulte").text("e = " + e);
    $(".resultf").text("f = " + f);
    $(".resultg").text("g = " + g);
```